# AsyncTask Андроид

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Не доходит до метода doInBackground при выключенном интернете на устройстве, в чем может быть ошибка?
Поток проверяет не изменилось ли значение с SharedPreferances, если да, то меняет стиль элемента на экране.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity{
    SharedPreferences sp;
    int btnOper1;
    int btnOper2;
    public Handler h;
    CheckPref checkPref;
    InterstitialAd interstitial;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1768060289488574/5823162247");
        // Создаём запрос к AdMob
        AdRequest adRequesti = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
// Начинаем загружать объявление
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequesti);

        final RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.settings_pressed));
                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.settings));
//                        interstitial.show();
                        finish();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


         h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                style();
            }
        };

        style();
    }
        @Override
    public void onPause() {

        if (isOnline()) interstitial.show();
            checkPref.cancel(true);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
                cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        LinearLayout linerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        linerLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0));
        checkPref = new CheckPref();
        checkPref.execute();
        super.onResume();
    }
    public void style(){

        LinearLayout liner = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liner);

        btnOper2 = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("operations", "0"));
    if (btnOper2 == 0) {
        liner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ravno_blue);
    } else if (btnOper2 == 1) {
        liner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ravno_green);

    } else if (btnOper2 == 2) {

        liner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ravno_red);
    } else if (btnOper2 == 3) {
        liner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ravno_yellow);
    } else if (btnOper2 == 4) {

        liner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ravno_orange);

    } else if (btnOper2 == 5) {

        liner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ravno_pink);
    }
    }

    class CheckPref extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           try{
               while (true){
                        btnOper1 = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("operations", "0"));
                        if (btnOper1!=btnOper2)  h.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                   System.out.println("###################");
                   Thread.sleep(100);
               }
           }catch (Exception e){
               System.out.println(e);
           }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не могу определить, в чем проблема в вашем коде, но вы в нем пытаетесь изобрести велосипед, который уже давным-давно доведен до совершенства, и называется он [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)

Comment: как к нему обращаться? это же listener?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, действительно велосипед был ещё тот)